# Rudin Theorem 6.17 - Trying to understand a step in the proof

Tags: real-analysis

Perhaps I'm just being obtuse, but I am struggling to understand a step in Rudin's proof of the following theorem: 
[image: Theorem Statement]

The step I am stuck on is the following: 
[image: Step]

I don't see how he passes from the absolute value expression bounded by $M\epsilon$, to moving the infimum of one part of that same expression out of the absolute value and over to the right.

If he had broken the absolute value, moved the terms over, and taken the infimum of both sides and immediately concluded the 4th line in the above image, it makes more sense to me.

Thank you!

Comment: I think that you have already understood: Rudin, simply, did not write all the steps you have listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\lvert a-b\rvert <M\varepsilon\iff b-M\varepsilon\le \color{red}{a \le b+M\varepsilon}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I see your hint but I don't understand that since U(P, fa') < the right sum in the absolute value, how can one replace b in your above logic with U(P, fa') in order to make Rudin's conclusion in the third equation?

Comment: I suppose $U(P,f\alpha')$ is the least upper bound of the $b$s (what it is exactly is not explained in the images you linked to)?

Comment: Ahhh, the $U(P, f \alpha ')$ is defined as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} M_i \Delta x_{i}$, for $M_{i}$ the maximum of $f\alpha'$ on $[x_{i-1}, x_{i}]$ which means that it will be greater than or equal to the sum in the second line for all $s_{i}$, and thus:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(s_{i})\alpha'(s_{i})\Delta x_{i} \leq U(P, f \alpha')$ because of the above definition, and thus the result follows by rearranging as you described. 

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{i=1}^nf(s_i) \Delta \alpha_i-\sum_{i=1}^nf(s_i) \alpha'(s_i) \Delta x_i \leq \left| \sum_{i=1}^nf(s_i) \Delta \alpha_i-\sum_{i=1}^nf(s_i) \alpha'(s_i) \Delta x_i \right|$$